# MySQL restore GPG encrypted database from shell

Tags: mysql, encryption, gnupg, database-restore

I have a gpg-encrypted dump of a MySQL database.
I'm trying to restore it decrypting in a single command, but it doesn't work - I think - because I need to input two passwords, one for decrypting and one for accessing db, and it seems to mess things up.
What I do is:

```
gpg --decrypt dump.sql.gpg | mysql -u user -p db_name
```

It ask me the DB password and the gpg password "together", so that I can't type both.
Is it possible to have the password-requirement separated?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some parameters are missing:

1. mute gpg output to terminal: --quiet --no-tty
2. batch mode: --batch
3. --decrypt outputs the decription to console instead of to a file
4. remove spaces between -u and the username and -p and the password
5. provide the database you want the data (it may be in the dump though)

Something like:

gpg --quiet --no-tty --batch --decrypt dump.sql.gpg | mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD [database]

Hope it helps!